# Can Anyone help me out with regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I dont have much knowledge on Regular expression. Help me out if i could achieve the below,
Username must need to validate this.

1. Only contains alphanumeric characters, underscore and dot
2. Underscore and dot can't be at the end or start of a username
3. Underscore and dot can't be next to each other
4. Underscore or dot can't be used multiple times in a row

I have come up with this regular expression but i cant fulfill all the above.

```
/(?<![a-z_|.])([a-z](?:[a-z]|_|.(?!_.))+[a-z]|[a-z]{2})(?![a-z_|.])/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use more than one expression? This way would create few mistakes. Remember: Sometimes another developer has maintance your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any lookbehind. Simplify your regex to this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!(?:.*\.){2}|(?:.*_){2}|.*[._]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEALOK/4)

Comment: But in your demo last example is not valid `A_b.c_d.e` 2 dots 2 underscores, or am i false?

Comment: Thanks anubhava :), Point 4 not matched for this expression. Eg: t_e_s.t is valid as far as with the expression but actually it needs to be invalid. But i can use this expression for 3 pts and will build another expression for point 4.

Comment: @anubhava: eg: t_.est this allows. Point 3 Not satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

One way to rome... (simple and easy version)

```
if(substr_count($string,'_')<=1 //for rule 4.
    && substr_count($string,'.')<=1 //for rule 4.
    && substr_count($string,'._')===0 //for rule 3.
    && substr_count($string,'_.')===0 //for rule 3.
    && preg_match('/^[^_\.][a-zA-Z]+[^_\.]$/',$string)// for rule 1. & 2.
) {
     echo 'Valid';
}
```

Comment: eg: A_B is valid one.

Comment: @shyammtp IS it good or bad? All rules fit on `A_B`. But nevermind you got ur answer. Dont get the downvote here?